# Extbase: implement locking for concurrent access

Tags: scheduled-tasks, typo3, extbase, concurrentmodification

In my extension I have a set of operations that are generated by user activities. Each operation consists of several steps.

To handle those operations I implemented a scheduler task (extension "scheduler" 6.2.0). Now the point is: steps of each operation must be done one after the other, not parallel. That means: at start the scheduler task should find next "free" operation, lock it and handle it.

For locking purposes database table with operations has an integer column "isLocked". So I wanted to use following SQL statement to lock an operation:

`$lockID = time();
'UPDATE operations SET isLocked = '.$lockID.' WHERE isLocked = 0 AND uid = '.$freeOperationFound->getUid().';`'

After this SQL command I wanted to check if lock was set:

```
$repository->findOneByIsLocked($lockID);
```

If locking was successful operation step handling can start.

If meanwhile another instance of scheduler task locks this operation, the SQL statement above does nothing because of condition: `WHERE isLocked = 0`.

The problem is: Extbase ignores SQL UPDATE-statements.

If I just update the free operation object via repository the lock of another task instance can be overwritten. I need some kind of "conditional" update.

Comment: How do you call your SQL statement? Why not use extbase to update the objects? If you don't have a good reason to not use extbase and need help I'll write out a detailed answer.

Comment: The point is: I cannot call this SQL-Statement, because Extbase ignores it. 
If I update the object - I risk to overwrite a lock of another instance, which set it's lock between my read and write operations.
And - yes! - I would be very grateful if you could write some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it: `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery` is the answer.

The only question remaining is, if this method is also depricated in FLOW, like `$query->statement` of Repository.

Answer (score 0):

While the exec_UPDATEquery function from the DatabaseConnection class certainly gets the job done, here is the solution via extbase. It might make more sense if you need to work with the Operation object after you lock it.

```
$persistenceManager = GeneralUtilities::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\extbase\Persistence\PersistenceManager');

$freeOperation = $repository->findOneByIsLocked(0);
$freeOperation->setIsLocked(time());

$repository->update($freeOperation);
$persistenceManager->persistAll();

$freeOperation->myOperation();
$freeOperation->myOtherOperation();

$freeOperation->setIsLocked(0);
$repository->update($freeOperation);
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

The reason why you need to persist manually is, that your task is not within the context of a ActionController Action. And even if you were, it wouldn't automatically persist your changes until the end of the Action. Doing it through extbase might be the safer option because you can be sure to actually work on the exact same operation that you have just locked.

Comment: I think it wouldn't go:  
What if in the meanwhile another instance tries to lock the same record:  
Look at this scenario:  
**A**`...$repository->findOneByIsLocked(0);` 
**B**`...$repository->findOneByIsLocked(0);` 
**A**`...->setIsLocked(time());`  
**A**`$repository->update($freeOperation);`  
**A**`$persistenceManager->persistAll();`  
**B(for some reason later as A)**`...->setIsLocked(time());`  
**B**`$repository->update($freeOperation);`  
**B**`$persistenceManager->persistAll();`
What we get is: "A" thinks it locked the record and "B" thinks it did!